# Write a expression in an another way

Tags: calculus

$\{ a,b,c \neq 0 \}$
$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{a}  = k$

$\frac{a}{c} + \frac{c}{b} + \frac{b}{a}  = l$

Using $k$ and $l$ write in an another way the expression
$\frac{a^3}{b^3} + \frac{b^3}{c^3} + \frac{c^3}{a^3} $

Comment: What have you tried? Also, $\frac{a^3}{b^3}+\cdots$ is not an **equation**; it's an **expression**.

Comment: Regarding the classification, where's the calculus? This looks like an algebra problem to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\;\;u^3+v^3+w^3 = (u+v+w)^3 - 3(u+v+w)(uv+vw+wu) + 3uvw$

Answer (score 1):

Begin with

\begin{align}
\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{a}=k &\implies \frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{a}{c}+\frac{c}{b}=\frac{a}{b}k \\
 &\implies \frac{a^2}{b^2}+l-\frac{b}{a}=\frac{a}{b}k \\
 &\implies \frac{a^3}{b^3}+\frac{a}{b}l-1=\frac{a^2}{b^2}k.
\end{align}

Similarly,
$$
\frac{b^3}{c^3}+\frac{b}{c}l-1=\frac{b^2}{c^2}k
$$
and
$$
\frac{c^3}{a^3}+\frac{c}{a}l-1=\frac{c^2}{a^2}k.
$$

Adding these three results together gives
$$
\frac{a^3}{b^3}+\frac{b^3}{c^3}+\frac{c^3}{a^3} + kl - 3 = k \left(\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{c^2}+\frac{c^2}{a^2} \right).
$$

Now, observe that
$$
k^2 = \frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{c^2}+\frac{c^2}{a^2} + 2\left(\frac{a}{c}+\frac{c}{b}+\frac{b}{a} \right) = \frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{c^2}+\frac{c^2}{a^2} + 2l.
$$

Therefore, substituting we find
$$
\frac{a^3}{b^3}+\frac{b^3}{c^3}+\frac{c^3}{a^3} = k(k^2-2l)+3-kl = k^3 -3kl + 3.
$$